# backbone render this.$el.html(this.template(data)) slow. what to do?

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, render

I have a collection to show.

```
1. for each model in collection, create a View
2. append view.render().el
```

I find view.render() takes long, more specifically 
`this.$el.html(this.template(data))` part.

I need to speed things up and found 'DOM manipulation' is slow.
So I looked for the ways to batch process the rendering but didn't find much.

- Question 1.
  I wonder if there is a way to batch process and attach the final html to the DOM without attaching each row to the DOM?
  (I suspect this.$el.html() does the DOM manipulation. If so, can I somehow not perform the `this.$el.html()` call in view.render() and later assign the view's el to decrease the DOM interaction?)
- Question 2.
  Are there other pitfalls or performance blocker when redering views in clients?

**edit**

```
  addAll: function() {

    this.$('#thread-loop').html('');

    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.threads.length; i++) {
      console.log('adding one');
      var thread = this.threads.at(i);
      var View = this.threadTypeToViewMap[thread.get('thread_type')];

      var view = new View( {model: thread, forumSelector: this.forumSelector} );

      fragment.appendChild(view.render().el);
    }
    this.$el.find('#thread-loop')[0].appendChild(fragment);

    // this.threads.each(this.addOne, this);

  },
```

Actually, I realised I'm using the fragment technique.

I nailed down the problem more and it looks like when javascript object has lengthy property (user created data), handlebar takes long to find the property (or so I suspect) in template() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://marionettejs.com

They extend Backbone to provide views that are optimized for collections (so you can create the DOM nodes in a loop and only add them to the document after you are done).  This is going to really help you with performance.

As for question 2, the things that will give you pitfalls are:

- Extensive DOM manipulation
- Compiling templates on the client instead of the server (i.e. making individual requests for each template after loading your page)
- General JavaScript performance bottlenecks (e.g. using polyfill foreach loops using jQuery or underscore instead of native JS, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Backbone template renders are slow because by default, they use JavaScript's `with` structure to scope the variable names properly as you expect. A little-known feature of Backbone templates allows you to skip this rather large performance penalty by assigning a variable to put all your data in (typically just "data"):

```
var t = _.template('<%= data.x %>', null, {variable: 'data'});
template({x: 42});
```

instead of the normal:

```
_.template('<%= x %>');
template({x: 42});
```

Do this, and you will see *huge* performance gains. This will probably solve your performance issues immediately.

Benchmark: http://jsperf.com/underscore-template-function-with-variable-setting

Answer (score 0):

For Q1 ->
If your $el is not in the dom already, you can append all the $el's into a Document Fragment and then inject the Document Fragment into the page at once. JQuery's John Resig has written a nice writeup about how document fragments work : http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments

Comment: What if my $el (for the collection view) is already dom attached?

Comment: In that case I would override the renderer for that view to render all child nodes to a disconnected node then add them to the DOM.

Comment: I can use the fragment and build everything in the collection view.. but I need to link each item in DOM to backbone View(and it's el) so that I can interact with it later. So the question is.. i'm editing the question...

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could try on top of using the doc fragment:

1- If you want to use the for loop, cache the length prior to looping.  var threadLength = this.threads.length;

2- That said, I would opt for using _.each instead of the for loop.

3- if you do 2, the threads model should be easily accessed.  I don't know if there is any hit to using get(), but you could just access the model.attributes.thread_type directly.

3- Is your template cached?

4- Why are you changing the html of #thread-loop twice? Is that needed? If you need to access it twice, then cache that selector also.